# Why would I use flash in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

When would I need to use `flash('message')`? At the moment I just pass a variable with whatever message I need to display to the template. This seems to work fine for me, what am I missing?

```
{% if messageText %}
<div id="message">{{messageText}}</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Why are you concerned about this, can you share the source with us?

Comment: Your method does work, but it gets cumbersome if you have lots of pages that each can have several such messages.

Comment: With the above method you have to make sure you clear messageText after  each use. Flash does this automatically for you, as each message is only shown once.

Comment: Also, your example only works within the current request.  Flash is a way to display messages on the **next** request.

Comment: What John said, and what if you have 1+ messages, and in different categories? (e.g. error VS info) Custom code would get cumbersome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use it if you want to collect one or more messages across one or more requests, with optional categories. Your version only handles one message in the current request. Flashed messages are stored in the session until they are read with `get_flashed_messages`. For example, you flash a success message when the user submits a form, `redirect` to the next page, then display the message. [See the docs on message flashing.](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/patterns/flashing/#message-flashing-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

Flash messages are useful when you have to show a message to the user after a `redirect`.

Let's suppose you have two routes:

- /users
- /users/add

When you post a new user to the `/users/add` route, you'll save the user in the database and redirect the browser to the `/users` route to list registered users.

In the `/users/add` route view function you could `flash` a message like "User account saved". This message is stored in a cookie and when you do a `redirect` to the `/users` route, this message can be rendered to the user.